# Modify Excel sheet, write to new Excel file with formulas

Tags: python, excel

I need some help with modifying cells in an Excel sheet and writing it to a new one.

I am loading an Excel file into a dataframe. There, I am modifing 5 cells. Below those cells are some formulas. When I write the modifications to a new Excel file, the formulas are all gone.
How can I write my modifications to a new Excel file and keep the formulas from the original one?

Thanks.
Jan

Comment: Use `openpyxl` directly. Pandas doesn't preserve formulas.

Comment: Hoped I can do it with Pandas, but then I am switching to openpyxl. Thanks!